# Import of slanted quote in mysql

Tags: mysql, csv

I am trying to import a csv file as a table using `LOAD DATA INFILE` mysql command.

There is a row with data like this:

`1.5” Pipe`

Slanted quote gets converted to question mark on import.
I am using UTF8 character encoding.

How to fix this issue?

Note: the CSV file does not have a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Comment: Do you want to ignore " or want to load " ?

Comment: @MiyaG Keep it.  I want it to display in browser along with all the other unicode characters as well.